# Why does rails make header content lowercase?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httpwebrequest

I find this behavior a bit strange, I'm using `'net\http'` to do some restful communication to an internal API. For this I need to send a `multipart/form-data` request to our server. In my code I have this:

```
request["Content-Type"] = "multipart/form-data, boundary=AbCdE1"
```

The request created then looks like this:

```
"multipart/form-data, boundary=abcde1"
```

The problem is the body itself is using `AbCdE1` for its boundaries and it fails. Obviously I could use just lowercase letters, but for a more reliably unique boundary, having capitals is helpful. I have seen comments that rails makes headers lowercase, is there a good reason why it does this without my intervention?

Answer (score 1):

The correct delimiter for the Content-Type and the boundary is a semicolon... Have you tried to use a semicolon instead of the comma, to see if Rails still translate it to lowercase?

BTW check http://httparty.rubyforge.org/ for consuming RESTful webservices, the result is more elegant than writing `net/http` code.